# How to implement Alexa Audio Player Hints

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to implement an Alexa Audio player in node.js with support for the Echo Show.  I am able to stream the audio and display the meta data, but cannot seem to change the "hints" to be reflective of my skill.

I really don't want a hint about euro exchange rates (see photo below) which have nothing to do with my skill...

In my response object, I have even included a display template that should not be necessary, but is included because I have tried everything else I know to try.

Can someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction.

```
'metaDataTestIntent': function() {
    console.log("begin meta data test");
    const { slots } = this.event.request.intent;

    this.attributes.streamURL = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rglage21wwfv1vj/A%20Satisfied%20Mind.mp3?dl=0';
    this.attributes.testTitle = "Stream Slots Title";
    this.attributes.testSubTitle = "Stream Slots SubTitle";
    try {
        switch (parseInt(slots.selectionNumber.value)) {
            case 1:
                this.attributes.streamURL = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/11cvh79rcgvqdkt/slippinaway.mp3?dl=0';
                this.attributes.testTitle = "Stream 1 Title";
                this.attributes.testSubTitle = "Stream 1 SubTitle";
                break;
            case 2:
                this.attributes.streamURL = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rglage21wwfv1vj/A%20Satisfied%20Mind.mp3?dl=0';
                this.attributes.testTitle = "Stream 2 Title";
                this.attributes.testSubTitle = "Stream 2 SubTitle";
                break;
            default:
                this.attributes.streamURL = `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/11cvh79rcgvqdkt/slippinaway.mp3?dl=0`;
                this.attributes.testTitle = "Stream Default Title";
                this.attributes.testSubTitle = "Stream Default SubTitle";
        }
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR:${err.message}`);
    }

    //check to see if the device we're working with supports display directives or if simulator
    if(supportsDisplay.call(this)||isSimulator.call(this)) {
        console.log("has display:"+ supportsDisplay.call(this));
        console.log("is simulator:"+isSimulator.call(this));
        console.log(`streamURL=${this.attributes.streamURL}`);
        var content = {
            "streamURL" : this.attributes.streamURL,
            "title" : this.attributes.testTitle,
            "subtitle": this.attributes.testSubTitle,
            "templateToken" : "countryStrangerTemplate",
            "artwork" : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nphebzfzlfmfw1o/CountryStranger480x480.png?dl=0',
            "background" : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gddtwefakcon325/Background1024x640.png?dl=0',
            "hint" : 'Alexa, tell Country Stranger to Play my Playlist.',
            "askOrTell" : ":ask",
            "endSession" : false,
            "sessionAttributes": this.attributes
        };
        console.log('call renderAudio to process devices with cards');
        renderAudio.call(this, content);           
    } else {
        console.log('process response for devices without cards');
        this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', streamDynamic.url, streamDynamic.url, null, 0);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
},
.    
.
.
.
.
.
function renderAudio (content) {
console.log(`renderAudio: ${content.streamURL}`);
switch(content.templateToken) {
    case 'countryStrangerTemplate':
        var response = {
            "version": "1.0",
            "response": {
                "shouldEndSession": content.endSession,
                "sessionAttributes": content.sessionAttributes,
                "directives": [
                    {
                        "type": "Display.RenderTemplate",
                        "template": {
                            "type": "BodyTemplate2",
                            "token": "token",
                            "backButton": "HIDDEN",
                            "backgroundImage": content.background,
                            "title": "template title",
                            "textContent": {
                                "primaryText": {
                                    "text": "primaryText",
                                    "type": "PlainText"
                                },
                                "secondaryText": {
                                    "text": "secondaryText",
                                    "type": "PlainText"
                                },
                                "tertiaryText": {
                                    "text": "tertiaryText",
                                    "type": "PlainText"
                                },
                            },
                        },  
                        "type" : 'Hint',
                        "hint" : {
                            "type" : 'PlainText',
                            "text" : content.hint
                        },
                        "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                        "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                        "audioItem": {
                            "stream": {
                                "url": content.streamURL,
                                "token": content.streamURL,
                                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                            },
                            "hint" : {
                                "type" : 'PlainText',
                                "text" : content.hint
                            },
                            "metadata": {
                                "title": content.title,
                                "subtitle": content.subtitle,
                                "art": {
                                    "sources": [
                                        {
                                            "url": content.artwork
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "backgroundImage": {
                                    "sources": [
                                        {
                                            "url": content.background
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }              
        };

        this.context.succeed(response);
    break;


    default:
        console.log("default case taken");
        this.response.speak("Thanks for visiting, goodbye");
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    break; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding all of the directives in one object, rather than separate objects in the directives array. I'm guessing Alexa is just ignoring all of the previous directives and only looking at the last one (the audio player directive.) Try this for your response instead:

```
var response = {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "shouldEndSession": content.endSession,
        "sessionAttributes": content.sessionAttributes,
        "directives": [
            {  
                "type" : 'Hint',
                "hint" : {
                    "type" : 'PlainText',
                    "text" : content.hint
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                "audioItem": {
                    "stream": {
                        "url": content.streamURL,
                        "token": content.streamURL,
                        "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                    },
                    "metadata": {
                        "title": content.title,
                        "subtitle": content.subtitle,
                        "art": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "url": content.artwork
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "backgroundImage": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "url": content.background
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice how I tweaked your response to contain each individual directive (in this case the audio player play directive and the hint directive) contained in it's own set of curly braces. I also got rid of the render template directive, because, as you said, you shouldn't need it!

Comment: Same results. The background, the image, the title and subtitle all display correctly, but the hint is still a random saying supplied by Amazon.  Can't seem to override it. I read that you have to reboot the device because it caches some data, but I've done that after every change and still not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: I have also tried using the response builder to add the hint, but get same results.

Comment: @FlashSolutions What happens when you remove the hint directive completely? Does the hint still show up?

Comment: @FlashSolutions also have you tried testing the skill in the developer portal? I doubt the problem is with your Show caching the data, but in the off chance it is you could test it there to make sure.

Comment: That does not work because it is an unsupported device where audio is concerned.

Comment: @FlashSolutions Yeah I wondered if that was the case. I assumed it would still show you how the Show will display the the audio data, but I've never tried it myself

Comment: I also tried it on the Echo Spot, but the Spot does not show the Hint at all. Only the Echo Show does shows the hints.